# Edit mapping from other contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I have two contracts. One to manage quests and one to manage units. These units have an `uint exp` and are mapped to an id by `mapping(uint256 => Unit) public tokenToUnit;`.
Now I want to use the `Quest Contract` to increase the exp from an unit inside the `Unit Contract`.

**How can I edit an uint of a struct which is mapped to an id?**

What I've tried:

*Contract Units.sol*

```
function addUnitExp(uint256 _unitId, uint256 _exp, uint32 _type) public {
    Unit storage _unit = tokenToUnit[_unitId];
    _unit.defense = _exp;
}
```

*Contract Quests.sol*

```
function addUnitExp(uint256 _unitId, uint256 _exp) public {
    UnitsInterface data = UnitsInterface(unitsContract);
    data.addUnitExp(_unitId, _exp);
}
```

`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

PS: Etheremon is doing similar (increaseMonsterExp) [here](https://github.com/etheremon/smartcontract/blob/master/EtheremonBattle.sol#L948).

Thanks a lot :)

**Code to reproduce:**

*Units.sol*

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract Units {
    uint totalUnits;

    mapping(uint => Unit) public idToUnit;

    struct Unit {
        uint id;
        uint exp;
    }

    constructor() public {
        Unit storage _unit = idToUnit[totalUnits];
        _unit.id = totalUnits;
        _unit.exp = 0;
        totalUnits++;
    }

    function increaseUnitExp(uint _id, uint amount) public {
        Unit storage obj = idToUnit[_id];
        obj.exp = amount;
    }
}
```

*Quests.sol*

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract DataBase {
    function increaseUnitExp(uint _id, uint amount) public;
}
contract Quests {

    DataBase dc;

    constructor(address _dataContract) public {
        dc = DataBase(_dataContract);
    }

    // gate way 
    function increaseMonsterExp(uint _id, uint _amount) public {
        dc.increaseUnitExp(_id, _amount);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you've got `onlyModerators` up there, what did you expect?

Comment: @goodvibration thanks, but I tried the same without using the `onlyModerators` modifier and still get the same `revert` error.

Comment: Are you passing the correct address to Quests constructor? If it is not set correctly calling an invalid method cause a revert.

Answer (score 1):

You got `onlyModerators` modifier in `Units.sol`. So when you call `addUnitExp` in `Units.sol` from `Quests.sol`, the `msg.sender` is `Quests.sol`, and not the user who called that function.

Comment: thanks, but I tried the same without using the `onlyModerators` modifier and still get the same `revert` error.